# How to disable console.log() on production and display a banner?

Tags: javascript, frontend

Can anyone shed some light on how to disable `console.log()` on production? I have seen achievements as below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think you can simply overwrite `console.log`. Maybe better to use own log function and change it's behavior, though.

Comment: Thank you guys, how exactly to disable the console.log and print the banner *at the same time*?

Comment: Stop using `console.log` in your code; replace it with your own log function.

Comment: Why are you trying to disable `console.log`? Isn't printing the banner alone enough?

Answer (score 4):

Are you using some kind of module bundler ?
In webpack you have option to drop_console in build. What drop console does is remove all console.log statements from your code.
There is also npm module for same please take a look.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-remove-console
This is a bagel plugin and if you have babel setup you can use it.

If all this doesn't meet your requirements. You can simply override console.log statement or use custom logger as other answers have suggested.

Answer (score 3):

```
var DEBUG = false;
if(!DEBUG){
  if(!window.console) window.console = {};
  var methods = ["log", "debug", "warn", "info"];
  for(var i=0;i<methods.length;i++){
      console[methods[i]] = function(){};
 }
}
```

Comment: I like this approach, but patching global functions like this is usually a bad idea, it can cause really hard-to-find bugs down the road. I did something similar but created my own logging functions, I'll add them as another answer below.

Answer (score 1):

**Approach 1**: You can save the `console.log` to your own function and remove the original.

Something like:

```
writeConsoleLog = console.log; //save the log function in your own function
console.log = function(){} //override the original log function
console.log("Text"); //does nothing
writeConsoleLog("Text"); //mimics the console.log() and writes to the console
```

**Aproach 2:** You can `console.log` whatever is required first, then remove the log function like so

```
console.log("The content you want to print"); //will write to the console
console.log = function(){} //override the log function
console.log("Text"); //now it does nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace all console.log(...) in your code with some other custom function to display the log info as you want, for example in a `DIV` element.
But if you really want to override the console.log function, you can do it simply like as following (generally not recommended):

```css
#myLogDiv {color: #604040; border: 1px solid gray; padding: 5pt; }
```

```html
<script>
console.log = function(t) { 
    document.getElementById("myLogDiv").innerText += t + "\r\n"; 
  }
</script>


<div id="myLogDiv">» My Log: <br/></div>

<p>This is normal content</p>

<script>
console.log("hello");
</script>

<p>Other content...</p>

<script>
console.log("world!");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can enable and disable by this example!

```js
console.log("Before disabled logs");

const showLogs = false

if( !showLogs ) {
  console.log = function() {} 
}

console.log("After disabled logs #1");
console.log("After disabled logs #2");
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Dodo's answer, I created a simple logging scheme that lets me control the logging level based on the host (limit output in production) and a query parameter. Here's my solution:

```
(() => {
    const pageURL = new URL(location.href);
    const prodMode = pageURL.host == 'oomdraw.com';
    const logLevels = ['Debug', 'Info', 'Warn', 'Error'];
    const logLevel = pageURL.searchParams.get('ll') || (prodMode ? 'Error' :  'Debug');

    const ml = logLevels.indexOf(logLevel);

    for (let i = 0; i < logLevels.length; i++) {
        window[`log${logLevels[i]}`] = i >= ml ? console[logLevels[i].toLowerCase()] : () => {};
    }
    
    logDebug('debug messages enabled');
    logInfo('info messages enabled');
    logWarn('warn messages enabled');
    logError('error messages enabled');
})();
```